# Finding closed form of recurrence relation that has a modulus term: $a_{n+1} = \frac 3 2 a_n + \big(\frac 1 2\big)^{a_n \bmod 2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form for the following recurrence relation:

$$
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 0\\
a_{n+1} &= a_n + \bigg\lfloor \frac {a_n} 2 \bigg\rfloor + 1 &\text{for } n \geq 0\\
&= \frac 3 2 a_n +
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } a_n \text{ is even}\\
\frac 1 2 &\text{if } a_n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}\\
&= \frac 3 2 a_n + \bigg(\frac 1 2\bigg)^{a_n \bmod 2}\\
&= \frac 3 2 a_n + 1 - \frac {a_n \bmod 2} 2\\
&= \frac 3 2 a_n + \frac 1 4 \cos (\pi a_n) + \frac 3 4
\end{align}
$$

I wrote $a_{n+1}$ in $5$ different ways hoping one of the ways would make it easier to find a closed form.

I'm using the method in $1.1$ of ["generatingfunctionology" by Wilf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf):

Define $A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$.
Take the LHS of any of the $a_{n+1} = ...$ relations and multiply it by $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$. We get:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n+1} x^n &= a_1 + a_2 x + a_3 x^2 + a_4 x^3 + ...\\
&= \{(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 + ...) - a_0 \} / x\\
&= A(x) / x
\end{align*}
$$

since $a_0 = 0$.

Now, do the same to the RHS of one of the $a_{n+1} = ...$ relations. Let's use expression $(4)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} \bigg(\frac 3 2 a_n + \bigg(\frac 1 2\bigg)^{a_n \bmod 2}\bigg) x^n &=
\frac 3 2 \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n + \sum_{n \geq 0} \bigg(\frac 1 2\bigg)^{a_n \bmod 2} x^n\\
&= \frac 3 2 A(x) + \sum_{n \geq 0} \bigg(\frac 1 2\bigg)^{a_n \bmod 2} x^n
\end{align*}
$$

And if I use expression $(5)$ instead, I get:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac 3 2 A(x) + \sum_{n \geq 0} \bigg(1 - \frac {a_n \bmod 2} 2\bigg) x^n\\
= &\frac 3 2 A(x) + \frac 1 {1 - x} + \frac 1 2 \sum_{n \geq 0} ( a_n \bmod 2) x^n
\end{align*}
$$

> wherein we have used the familiar geometric series evaluation $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n = \frac 1 {1 − x}$, which is valid for $|x| < 1$.

If I use expression $(6)$ instead, I get:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac 3 2 A(x) + \sum_{n \geq 0} \bigg(\frac 1 4 \cos (\pi a_n) + \frac 3 4\bigg) x^n\\
= &\frac 3 2 A(x) + \frac 1 4 \sum_{n \geq 0} \cos (\pi a_n) x^n + \frac 3 4 \sum_{n \geq 0} x_n\\
= &\frac 3 2 A(x) + \frac 1 4 \sum_{n \geq 0} \cos (\pi a_n) x^n + \frac 3 4 \bigg(\frac 1 {1 - x}\bigg)
\end{align*}
$$

And this is where I am stuck, since I am not able to simplify away the remaining $a_n$ in any of the RHS's (Right Hand Sides).

The furthest I get is that:

$$
\begin{align*}
A(x) \bigg(1 - \frac 3 2 x\bigg) &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \bigg(\frac 1 2\bigg)^{a_n \bmod 2} x^{n+1}\\
&= \frac x {1 - x} + \frac 1 2 \sum_{n \geq 0} ( a_n \bmod 2) x^{n+1}\\
&= \frac 1 4 \sum_{n \geq 0} \cos (\pi a_n) x^{n+1} + \frac 3 4 \bigg(\frac x {1 - x}\bigg)
\end{align*}
$$

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: [`A006999`](https://oeis.org/A006999) @OEIS

Comment: Looks like this is a tough one. I fed the early part of the sequence into the OEIS search engine, and [this match](https://oeis.org/A006999) popped out. Apparently there is a formula of the form $a_n=-1+\lfloor c(3/2)^2\rfloor$, but the constant $c$ is unwieldy.

Comment: @metamorphy and Jyrki Lahtonen, the formula of the sequence `a(n+1) = (3*a(n))/2+1 if a(n) is even. a(n+1) = (3*a(n)+1)/2 if a(n) is odd.` with the first term of the sequence being `0` matches my recurrence relation, so it is the same sequence indeed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In the `CROSSREFS` section, it mentions `The constant c is 2/3*K(3) (see `[A083286](https://oeis.org/A083286)`)`.

Comment: For more references, see https://oeis.org/A061419 (this is the entry for $a_n + 1$).  This satisfies the recurrence $a_{n+1} = \lceil 3a_n/2 \rceil$.    Wolfram Mathworld has an entry on this sequence (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerCeilings.html) which observes that the formula $a_n = -1 + \lceil c(3/2)^n \rceil$ is not actually useful because to compute the constant $c$ requires knowing the $a_n$ in advance. The cited 1991 paper by Odlyzko and Wilf echoes this.

Comment: Btw, $a_n$ is the largest-index ($0$-indexed) square reachable in $n$ jumps in the Infinite Sidewalk: https://www.janestreet.com/numberphile/